# How to check what's wrong with visual studio code debugger

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, logging, configuration, visual-studio-code

I've spent a lot of time trying to find a reason why vscode debugger (vscode-chrome-debug module) doesn't work as expected. I didn't find any way how to enable logging in vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy, thanks to [Andreas](https://github.com/apazureck). You don't need to search additional vscode environment variables or config parameters. Just enable the diagnosticLogging option in your launch.json. It enables logs writing of vscode-chrome-debug module to ~/.vscode/extensions/msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome/vscode-chrome-debug.txt